# К какому виду относится придаточное предложение с союзом ЧТОБЫ?

Tags: грамматика, спп, тип-придаточных

**Было уже поздно, чтобы ехать куда-нибудь.**

Как определить вид СПП?

Для сравнения другой пример:
**Я опять встал поздно, чтобы успели уйти на работу родители.**

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

*Я опять встал поздно(зачем? с какой целью?), чтобы успели уйти на работу родители*. - придаточное цели.

*Было уже поздно (для чего?),(для того) чтобы ехать куда-нибудь*.- придаточное изъяснительное, поясняет главную часть. Местоимение **для того** опущено, поэтому местоимённо-определительным его назвать нельзя, только изъяснительным.

Comment: Мне кажется, что опорное слово "поздно" для изъяснительного придаточного не очень подходит. Я думала, что здесь  разновидность местоименно-союзной связи: поздно (в какой степени? - слишком поздно, то есть это придаточное  со значением степени признака и цели.. Сравнить: Было так поздно, что нельзя было ехать. Здесь придаточное степени и следствия.

Comment: Опорные слова для изъяснительного - все слова со значением чувства, мысли, речи. Поздно - категория состояния, это на грани чувства и ощущения, так что вполне подходит.  Было так поздно, что нельзя было ехать - действительно придаточное степени, но не следствия, но у нас легко вставляется местоимение для того, а не наречие так.

Comment: Тип придаточного мы определяем в большей степени по вопросу, по семантике.

Comment: По семантике мне кажется, что здесь выражено сопоставление, (соответствие или несоответствие), например: Сейчас уже холодно, чтобы так легко одеваться.

Comment: И в этом примере опущено подразумеваемое "слишком": холодно здесь в относительном смысле: настолько холодно (колич. мера), что так нельзя одеваться (следствие).

Comment: Сопоставления здесь никак нет. Сопоставительное: Если раньше я не справлялся с подобными заданиями, то теперь выполняю их быстро.  Polina, не стоит так углубляться, ведь здесь явно не цель, а пояснение  сказуемого главного предложения поздно. Поясняется, для чего поздно, придаточное отвечает на падежный вопрос. Следовательно, это придаточное изъяснительное. Сейчас открыла свою книгу "Экзаменационные ловушки", там указание на то, что могут быть придаточные с добавочным значением, вот добавочных здесь может быть много, но основное - изъяснительное, не надо ученикам забивать голову.

Answer (score 1):

По классификации Русской грамматики РАН 
( http://rusgram.narod.ru/3058-3077.html )

Как разновидность  СПП, это *фразеологизированная конструкция со значением обусловленности*, оформляемая двухместным союзным соединением "**достаточно (слишком) - чтобы**". В вашем примере "слишком" опущено,  но *должно* присутствовать (если не упрощать до "*Было уже поздно ехать куда-нибудь.*"):

Было уже **слишком** поздно, **чтобы** ехать куда-нибудь.

> § 3077. Позицию слова *достаточно* может занимать слово **слишком**, которое
>   указывает на градационные изменения признака; изменяющийся признак
>   может быть выражен прилагательным, наречием и глаголом (включая
>   причастие).
>
> *Работа **слишком** глубоко захватила меня, **чтобы** я мог
>   серьезно думать о своих отношениях к жене (Чехов).*

Что касается *классификации* отдельно взятого *придаточного* предложения. Розенталем такой тип предложения рассматривается в аспекте избыточности повторных частиц "бы" после "чтобы" (как стилистической ошибки); особенностью такого придаточного он называет *присутствие* в нём *глагола в условно-сослагательном наклонении*.

http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xlvii.html

Comment: Это предложение  из Л. Толстого:Когда он покончил дела, было уже поздно, чтобы ехать куда-нибудь, но было еще рано, чтобы ложиться спать,  Конечно, взаимообусловленность - это удобный способ классификации, но ведь есть базовые грамматические понятия: местоименная связь, союзная связь, местоименно-союзная связь и есть семантика отношений. Вот и хотелось бы по этим параметрам определиться: вид связи и  смысл отношений между главнм и придаточным (цель, условие,  сравнение, изъяснение или что-то другое).

Comment: Это **определительное** предложение (см. там же § 2821), в котором определительное значение выражается _через указание на следствие_, со значением меры количества (см. § 2856)

Comment: А откуда здесь возьмется следствие, такого союза в предложении нет. И вопрос: чтобы -  здесь изъяснительный союз или какой? Понимаете, мне не хочется для анализа простых предложений привлекать академическую грамматику. Нужен ответ, понятный каждому школьнику,  ведь это обычный тип предложений, которые часто используются в бытовых ситуациях. Можно их определить как разновидность СПП, которые изучаются в школьной программе (по грамматике, по смыслу)?

Comment: Следствие простое: ехать нельзя. Причина: слишком поздно. Посредством союза "чтобы" выражается _недостаточная мера количества_ (см. там же § 2845). Проще не получается, но предложение **не** изъяснительное, а _определительное_, как видно из ссылок.

Comment: Поправлюсь: _чрезмерная_ мера количества (по определению источника, § 2845).

Comment: **P. S.** По учебной классификации отдельно взятое придаточное здесь ближе всего к _обстоятельственным меры_. 
http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/291-vidypridatochnyhvslognopodchinennyhpredlogeniyah.html
Однако на вопрос "в какой степени (сейчас поздно)" оно даёт лишь косвенный ответ. Прямой вопрос: для чего сейчас слишком поздно? (Для того поздно,) чтобы ехать. Это отличается от  приводимого там примера _"Мы так устали, что не могли идти дальше."_ и по форме ближе к "_Мы слишком устали, чтобы идти дальше"_. В классификации РГ это _определительное ССП_.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, правда, я мало что поняла. Последний вопрос: союз чтобы какой: изъяснительный, цели, следствия?

Comment: http://rusgram.narod.ru/2853-2884.html Предложения со значением недостаточной, достаточной и чрезмерной степени качества или меры количества (с союзом чтобы)
§ 2853. Союз чтобы выступает здесь в значении союза что и выражает не целевые, а следственные отношения. На чрезмерную степень указывают наречия слишком и чересчур.

Answer (score 1):

> Было уже поздно, чтобы ехать куда-нибудь.

В учебном пособии Л.А. Дерибас и К.И. Мишиной "Типы предложений в русском языке" (М., 1981) похожее предложение (*"Было уже слишком поздно, чтобы ехать домой"*) рассматривается как **сложноподчинённое с придаточным цели**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В разбираемом нами предложении, правда, отсутствует опорное слово *слишком*, но оно ведь явно подразумевается? Думаю, что можно считать его просто опущенным.

Comment: Они только примыкают, но не являются придаточными цели. И цель здесь особенная - ирреальная, скорее говорится о возможности ехать, если бы возникло такое желание.  Мне вообще кажется, что весь смысл этой фразы заключен в следующем: сейчас поздно ехать (если бы вы захотели поехать). От цели почти ничего не осталось.

Comment: _Они только примыкают..._ === А разве этого мало?

Comment: Во втором разбираемом предложении ("я встал поздно, чтобы успели уйти родители") **слишком** никак не может подразумеваться, я думаю.

Comment: Это предложение  со значение цели, я его только для сравнения  привела.

Comment: А разве этого мало?  Думаю, что недостаточно.  Не стоит забывать: союз  чтобы у нас двуликий  (изъяснительный и целевой), а здесь гибрид какой-то.

Comment: Предложения со значением недостаточной, достаточной и чрезмерной степени качества или меры количества (с союзом чтобы)
§ 2853. Союз чтобы выступает здесь в значении союза что и выражает **не целевые, а следственные** отношения. На чрезмерную степень указывают наречия слишком и чересчур. § 2856 _Я слишком проста, чтобы понимать вас (Чехов)_
http://rusgram.narod.ru/2853-2884.html