# Чтобы vs. что бы

Tags: орфография

Правильно я думаю, что надо писать *чтобы*?

> У нас опыта мало, что( )бы судить работу педагогов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**чтобы**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%8B) и **чтоб**, ***союз*** (говори громче, чтобы все слышали; хочу, чтобы все это поняли) и *частица* (чтобы я тебя здесь больше не видел!); но ***местоим.*** что бы (что бы предпринять?)

Сомневаетесь? При использовании местоимения "что" с частицей "бы" (**что бы**) частицу можно из предложения изъять — без потери смысла, с союзом же такой "фокус" не пройдет.

Попробуем: *У нас опыта мало, **что** судить работу педагогов.*
При "уничтожении" частицы "бы" предложение теряет смысл.
Вывод: это союз **чтобы**.

*Средняя школа плодит дилетантов, полагающих, что их ущербного знания вполне достаточно, чтобы судить профессионалов»* (С. Н. Есин. Дневник).
*Этого, к сожалению, слишком мало, чтобы судить о современном французском кинематографе* (Т. И. Бачелис. Вопросительный знак).

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, какой здесь вид союза ЧТОБЫ: изъяснительный или цели?

Comment: Думаю, 1-й, т. к. там целью отнюдь как не пахнет.

Comment: А вот здесь целая дискуссия по этому вопросу https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443489/К-какому-виду-относится-придаточное-предложение-с-союзом-ЧТОБЫ